# Disable shell access in docker-image

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I'm new to using Docker and need to use a lean OpenJDK 17 base-image to create an image of a Java web application and disable the ability of a user to log into a running container.

I've tried to use [amazoncoretto 17 alpine](https://github.com/corretto/corretto-docker/blob/main/17/jdk/al2/Dockerfile) image which purportedly has shell access disabled.

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine3.15    
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/myapp.jar"]
```

But still you can log in to a container created off of this image, using `docker exec -it my-container sh`, which I need to prevent.

What is the best way of accomplishing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to uninstall bash/ash/sh if you want to remove exec capabilites

Comment: Alternatively, use distroless java... Or, clarify what you mean by "purportedly"

Comment: "Disable the user to run into a running container" -- if that user has root and is a competent sysadmin, you can't. Full-stop impossible. Someone with root can use `nsenter` to get into any container they like. Someone with root can add more files to a container even if it _has_ no shell. Remember, the tools that Docker itself is built on top of are all _things that someone with root can do without Docker_.

Comment: There's also some discussion of this in [How do I prevent root access to my docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57731428/how-do-i-prevent-root-access-to-my-docker-container) (TL;DR: you can't).  With Java the situation is a little better than purely-interpreted languages since the most an end user could do is extract the jar file, rather than the source code directly (but a true compiled language would be better still).  What are you trying to protect against?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be to remove the `sh` symlink from the container, with `RUN rm /bin/sh`.

Alpine uses links to busybox for these functionalities, which can be deleted to remove the functionality

```
# ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  root 12 Aug  9 08:47 /bin/sh -> /bin/busybox
```

Any other non required functionality can be disabled same way.

Busybox doc

> BusyBox is a multi-call binary that combines many common Unix
> utilities into a single executable.  Most people will create a link to
> busybox for each function they wish to use and BusyBox will act like
> whatever it was invoked as.

Comment: That'll stop `docker exec` from working. It certainly won't stop `nsenter` from working.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `nsenter` is also symlink to busybox, can be disabled similar to sh, by deleting the symlink `/usr/bin/nsenter -> /bin/busybox`

Comment: You miss the point. `nsenter` can be used _outside_ the container to enter it. It doesn't matter if there's a copy inside the container at all.

Comment: ...and while a stock copy of nsenter may not be able to set an arbitrary argv[0], it wouldn't be hard to compile one that can, such that as long as _any_ busybox binary is available, `sh` also remains available.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. @s3vt, I tried this but  it actually prevented the container from running on `docker run`.

Comment: @s3vt What functionalities are the minimum required for the system to run or can I delete the whole folder and run a java app inside the image?